# context.clearRect() doesnot work when giving tooltip option a graph using chat.js

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas

Am using chat.js to plot a graph. In a particular event (mouse event) this graph is cleared and redrawn with new values. For clearing the canvas where graph the graph is drawn i use

*context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.hight);*

This clears the canvas and i can redraw the graph. But when i take my mouse pointer on to the plotted area( for tooltip function), graph is showing strange behavior. Its showing the value which are cleared and also the new values.

I have tried the same by disabling the tooltip option and it doesn't have any problem and works as expected.

I need to put the tooltip also. How can i solve the issue.